# Merging array keys in multidimentional array does not give desired output

Tags: php

This is my generated array
i have tried `array_merge_recrusive` but not successful.
I am doing program it should generate this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [assistment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [assistment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                )

        )
required
    [6] => Array
        (
            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [assistment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

I want following output array 
I have tried lot of but not find this type of output

```
Array
(

            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )




            [assistment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )




            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [0] => 4
                )



            [assistment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )



            [competancy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [0] => 7
                )



            [assistment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )



)
```

Comment: You'll most likely get negative voting if you don't include some of what you have tried.

Comment: When including your input and output arrays, use `var_export` or write as code as it makes it easier for people to work with the data.  Try also to keep your data to a minimum of what is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try to merge array with splat :

```
print_r(array_merge(...$array));
```